# Can't access jQuery DOM ready scope for debugging

Tags: javascript, scope

```
$(function(){ var my_value = 'text1'})
```

but in the console(safari console I use), I don't know how to access my_value variable, since it's the local variable in the function(){} scope.

Any work around or better solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to breakpoint that line of javascript.  When you step over that line, you should be able to inspect the value happily.

Answer (score 0):

Unfold your code block so you can set a breakpoint on your specific line. You can also use the keyword `debugger;` to explicitly set a breakpoint:

```
$(function(){
    debugger;
    var my_value = 'text1';
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, you could either add a breakpoint to your javascript code or define a local watch variable in the console which shows you the value of your variable you defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass data and functions as an object to `window` as I have done below:

```
(function(global){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var my_value = 'text1',
        aPublicFunction = function(){
          // blah blah
        },
        aPrivateFunction = function(){
          // blah blah
        };

    // prepare what you want window to see.
    global.publicAPI = {
      my_value: my_value,
      aFunction: aFunction
    }
  });
})(window);

publicAPI.my_value;
// 'text1'

publicAPI.aPrivateFunction();
// no can do!
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, make use of the debugger.

For Safari (and Chrome), check out [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW1), or [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) if you're using Firefox.